# How to prevent Jar file from being converted to zip on macOS"?

Tags: java, macos, executable-jar

I have created a java application and created an executable-jar file. Now, I sent this jar file to my friend. My friend is using macOS. When he downloads the jar file it automatically gets converted to .zip file. When we unzip that file we get another .cpgz file. He also have the latest version of java jre installed. I don't know why its happening.

I have searched the internet. But everybody is talking about opening jar files. But my problem is that I want to have jar file in macOS.

Can somebody please help me to download the jar file and keep it from being converted to .zip

Answer (score 0):

If your friend is using Safari to download the file, try **unchecking** the following checkbox in Safari Preferences.
[image]

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. I think this might work